# How to set cookie so I can read from same domain with different port?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have set my cookie through my C# code using Request.Cookie["NTLogin"].Value="XYZ" . I want to read this cookie from my new application when I do handoff. The new application is written in Angular JS code. I am accessing this cookie through 
$cookies.get('UserNTLogin');

Here is the old URL
http://localhost/handoff.aspx

New URL:
http://localhost:81/home.html

When I access it using 
$cookies.get('UserNTLogin'); I get value as undefined

Need help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

> **8.5.  Weak Confidentiality**
>
> Cookies do not provide isolation by port

I suspect that the issue is that you use

```
Request.Cookie["NTLogin"].Value="XYZ"
```

Instead of

```
Response.Cookie["NTLogin"].Value="XYZ"
```

See also MSDN "[How to: Write a Cookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx)"

Anyway you can always use developer tools in your browser or Fiddler to see if cookie is actually set by the server in the first response.